# Is "Event Bubbling" supported in ObjC?

Tags: objective-c, event-bubbling

Does Objective-C support the idea of "Event bubbling"?

For those unfamiliar: the idea is that you dispatch/release a notification on an object of sorts and every containing item is notified, one object at a time, starting with the closest in the hierachy until the entire object list (usually a display list) is notified.

Comment: I am not sure about the language, but cocoa [provides a mechanism to achieve that effect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) through the `forwardInvocation:` mechanism.

Comment: Are we doing markup practice? To the extent that what you're describing might be thought of as a *language* feature, it isn't a feature of Obj-C. But frankly it sounds more like a usage pattern, which it would be possible to implement explicitly and which does resemble some common Cocoa idioms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you may be referring to the *Responder Chain*. If so, then the easy answer is "yes". But as one commenter has pointed out, this is a framework feature, not a language feature. The Responder Chain is different between Cocoa (OS X) and Cocoa Touch (iOS), so you would have to specify which framework you're using to get a specific answer.

Responder Chain documentation for Cocoa can be found here: [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2)

Responder Chain documentation for Cocoa Touch can be found here: [Event Handling Guide for iOS: Event Types and Delivery](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW5)